# Use Karma testrunner On Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm new to javascript unit testing. To learn karma + jasmine, I've been writing unit tests for a Chrome Extension project of mine. That has worked pretty well for the modules and functions which don't use the chrome object, but I have no idea how to test the extension parts of it.

For instance, I might want to set the proxy with chrome.proxy.settings.set(...), and then verify that it was successfully set with chrome.proxy.settings.get(...).

Is there a way to run tests from the extensions global scope? Or any other way to accomplish these tests.

Comment: _"Is there a way to run tests from the extensions global scope?"_ I do not understand your question.

Comment: Sorry, run tests on the actual extension instead of individual bits of javascript. So I can issue commands to the extension and have chrome respond.

Comment: Let me be more specific. The Karma test runner works by opening a page in a browser and running the js in that page. Chrome extensions are allowed to do cross site scripting so there should be a way to open the karma page within the extension and give the test runner in scope to control the extension.

Comment: @JoshHorowitz did you solve it?